# Aggregate $Lookup for several mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I am linking records from different collections with mongodb the following way:

```
mongoose.model(job.data.dataset).aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "btc.mobile.accountList",
            localField: "account",
            foreignField: "account",
            as: "userAccountData"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "btc.mobile.imsiList",
            localField: "imsi",
            foreignField: "imsi",
            as: "userImsiData"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "btc.mobile.productList",
            localField: "tariffCode",
            foreignField: "tariffCode",
            as: "userProductData"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$userAccountData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $unwind: { path: "$userImsiData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
    { $unwind: { path: "$userProductData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }}
    ], function(err, result){

    });
```

Expected result is a json object that contains all the properties in the different collections at the same level.

But in this case it will merge everything and then provide it in the result the aggregated collection. What I want to do is get the result for each aggregation so then I can work each record individually.

How can I do that?

I want to be able to then apply several functions I have in Javascript to the linked record. LIke check if a property has length > 10. Or what is the type of another property.

Comment: What would you like to do with each record ? Can you add expected json output  and some sample input documents too ?

Comment: I have functions that process the each records. Like see if a value in parm1 has length > 10. I also want to produce statistics based on each record.

Comment: its still little unclear. consider adding the details asked that would clarify your intent.  so state before unwind was not good ?

Comment: @Veeram what do you mean by state before unwind was not good? I do the unwind so that I can have all the properties at the same level on the json document. I dont wish to have arrays inside it.

Comment: okay so you dont need arrays and merged documents. What is the expected output then ?

Comment: The expected output is a json object that contains all the properties of the different linked collections at the same level.

Comment: That makes sense now. It may be possible in 3.6.

Comment: @Veeram right, I just don't know exactly how.